# Can I optimize garbage collection with inline classes?

Tags: kotlin, garbage-collection

I am working on a game with java.swing and java.awt, with repainting every few ms.
As I was browsing the web to gather what errors shouldn't be made, I stumbled several time upon warnings about the Garbage Collector (GC). In particular, generating many instances of a class (generally, it is the Vector class) and then throwing them away at each mainloop's end will make the GC collect these very frequently, resulting in small, frequent lags that can be very frustrating.

I realized my code needed a LOT of Vector instances (which are actually a wrapper on a (x,y) Int pair), a bunch of them being only used in intermediate computations.

I am working with Kotlin, and was thinking about a possible solution. The first thing would be to create a MutVector class, of which you can re-set x and y properties. However I do not like this solution, as I find it counter-intuitive and error-prone.

I then thought about this : Kotlin offers inline classes (now @JVMInline value classes), which behave like wrappers on a specific type. For example, you can declare :

```
@JVMInline 
value class EmailAdress(val value: String) {
    fun getHost() {
        return value.split("@").last()
    }
}
```

Which is a dinstinct type from String, have its own methods, but is represented at run-time (in most of the cases, see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-classes.html) as a simple String, thereby avoiding runtime overhead.
Due to how primitives are optimized, when used as a wrapper around Int, Long, etc, it allows gaining quite a lot of time. In particular, from what I gathered, the GC doesn't have to collect primitives.

So, I thought about this :

```
private fun checkWontOverflow(x: Int): Int {
    // Value chosen because 2^31 - 1 misbehaves with shl, and for the usage I'm doing of it, it doesn't matter (it'll store coordinates smaller than 100,000)
    // much between 2^30 and 2^31
    require(abs(x) < 2.0.pow(30))
    return x
}

@JVMInline
value class Vector private constructor(private val storage: Long) {
    constructor(x: Int, y: Int): this(checkWontOverflow(x).toLong() shl 32 + checkWontOverflow(y).toLong())

    val x: Int
        get() = (storage shr 32).toInt()

    val y: Int
        get() = (storage - x shl 32).toInt()
}
```

Which seems to be behaving correctly.
However I wanted to know :

- Is there cases where it can misbehave (I fear it might overflow)
- Will it really help the GC out and remove lags ?
- Is there an easier way to achieve that ?
- I'd like to have a (x: Float, y: Float) Vector. Can I do something similar by merging two Float-s into a (probably non-sensical) Double ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help with GC issues so long as you aren't putting instances into Arrays or Lists, which would cause boxing them into class instances in the bytecode.

I would do this with bit manipulation so there are no concerns about overflow:

```
@JvmInline
value class IntVector private constructor(private val storage: Long) {
    constructor(x: Int, y: Int): this((x.toLong() shl 32) or (y.toLong() and 0xFFFFFFFFL))

    val x: Int
        get() = (storage shr 32).toInt()

    val y: Int
        get() = storage.toInt()
}
```

And for Floats:

```
@JvmInline
value class FloatVector private constructor(private val storage: Long) {
    constructor(x: Float, y: Float): this((x.toRawBits().toLong() shl 32) or (y.toRawBits().toLong() and 0xFFFFFFFFL))

    val x: Float
        get() = Float.fromBits((storage shr 32).toInt())

    val y: Float
        get() = Float.fromBits(storage.toInt())
}
```

If you do need to keep them in a collection of some kind, you could make `storage` and the primary constructor `internal` and create a class that wraps a `LongArray` and passes values in and out without boxing, for example:

```
class IntVectorArray(val size: Int) {
    private val array = LongArray(size)
    operator fun get(index: Int): IntVector = IntVector(array[index])
    operator fun set(index: Int, value: IntVector) {
        array[index] = value.storage
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clear answer ! I only have one question, what is the "and 0xFFFFFFFFL" for ?

Comment: The sign of `y` extends to the leftmost bits after converting it to a long so we need to 0 out the first 32 bits with this operation before we `or` it with the left-shifted `x`.

Comment: But then won't it erase said sign ?

Comment: Not the one still sitting in the 32nd bit. We aren't touching the right-most 32 bits when we use `and 0xFFFFFFFFL` so that data is preserved.